# Parsing Date from String

Tags: java, xml, parsing, date

I have the following timestamp stored as a String that I would like to parse using `SimpleDateFormat` but I'm having some issues with converting:

My TimeStamp which I read in from an xml file: `Tue Dec 31 09:29:08 PDT 2013`

My Code:

```
String timeStamp = innerNode.getTextContent();   //innerNode is a Node object that contains my TimeStamp from an xml file.
System.out.println(timeStamp);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PDT"));
dateFormat.parse(timeStamp);

Date firstParsedDate = dateFormat.parse(timeStamp);
System.out.println(firstParsedDate);
```

So that works great but my result is strange.  Instead of printing `Tue Dec 31 09:29:08 PDT 2013` my result is instead:  `Tue Dec 31 11:29:08 CDT 2013`

Any ideas what is wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date.toString` won't use the time zone you entered for the `SimpleDateFormat` that created it. Instead, you should do:

```
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(firstParsedDate));
```

This should use the correct time zone that you set on the formatter. `toString` just uses the system time zone.

Comment: Of course. Note that the time you got is still correct (9:29 PDT is the same as 11:29 CDT). So your parser is working. Also note that you don't have to set the time zone to parse it. Since you used a `z` in your format string, it can figure it out for you when it parses it. In your case, the time zone is just for printing.

Answer (score 1):

A date object in java will use the system time zone. Your system is in CDT timezone and not in PDT. So the date is being printed in CDT.